# Reputation Alert and Details Inconsistent

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

I logged in this morning after being away for a few days and noticed that the "summary" count of my rep change was different from the recent details...

[image]

I know there are nuances with calculations and removed questions, but wanted to mention this in case there was something else at play. The hard part is trying to reproduce this, since as soon as I'm done checking the updates, it goes away.

Comment: *"The hard part is trying to reproduce this, since as soon as I'm done checking the updates, it goes away."* This was the perfect situation to ask for upvotes to reproduce that issue and you've missed it :/.

Comment: Your freehand circles are disgusting.  Shame!

Comment: @Will I don't think that's Freehand. I think it's Skitch.

Comment: @yivi they're gross is what they are!  Gross!